# Is there any performance overhead due to android emulation on linux?

Tags: linux, android, container, emulation

Is there any performance overhead due to android emulation on linux since android uses a linux kernel. Does it utilize the underlying kernel to achieve minimum performance overhead similar to a container. I am currently using Anbox for emulation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [anbox website](https://anbox.io/):

> Anbox puts Android apps into a tightly sealed box without direct access to hardware or your data.

So the emulation isn't hardware passthrough, which does mean overhead, however

> Anbox runs the Android system under the same kernel as the host operating system does

So there is less slowdown than on full-blown emulators.

Comment: Is there any emulator with no such overhead.

Comment: There's always going to be some overhead when emulating, UNLESS you use a cloud application, in which case the bottleneck is in external servers.  You could also look for just a compatibility layer that doesn't deal with containerization/emulation if you just want to run android apps (without hardware virtualization).